# C# Winforms: How to get CenterParent with SubForms and ModalForms to function?

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-positioning

I have a **MainForm** with a subform **SubLevel1** within a panel. In **SubLevel1** I have another subform **SubLevel2** which is opened in a panel within **SubLevel1**. Now, from **SubLevel2** I am opening a **ModalForm** with `ShowDialog()` and I want to center it above **SubLevel2** resp. **MainForm** (in which **SubLevel2** is included through **SubLevel1**).

`CenterParent` just does not work and am not able to get the correct (relative) location to position the **ModalForm** correctly:

1. I am not able to set **SubLevel2** as `Parent` of the **ModalForm**: "a top level control can not be added to a control" error pops up. Therefore, `Parent` of the **ModalForm** is always `null`.
2. When I set **SubLevel2** as `Owner` of **ModalForm**, it always has the location `0,0` which cannot be used to position the **ModalForm**.
3. When I use `ownerLocation = modalForm.Owner.PointToClient(Point.Empty)` the position is not correct.
4. When I use `ownerLocation = modalForm.Owner.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)` the position is not correct.

When creating the **SubForms** I do it as follows:

```
  _FormSub = new FormSub() {
    TopLevel = false,
    TopMost  = false
  };
  panelSub.Controls.Add(_FormSub);
  _FormSub.Show();
```

When creating the **ModalForm** within the code of **SubForm2** I do it as follows:

```
  formModal = new formModal() {
    Owner = this
  };
  formModal.ShowDialog();
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Why are you using `ShowDialog`? Why not just put a panel on the main form?

Comment: Owner = this.FindForm();

Comment: @Enigmativity: I want to center a modal dialogue form above a window.
@HansPassant: This did not work if the owner is not set and does not solve the problem when the owner's location is `0,0`.
Found a solution, see below.

Comment: @tar - Yes, I understood that. Can you answer my question?

Comment: @tar - Also, you can only `@` one person in each comment. Hans would not have gotten a notification.

Comment: @Enigmativity: ??? How does a panel solve the positioning of a new dialogue window?

Comment: @tar - It doesn't. I'm wondering why you are trying to position a dialog, when just putting a panel on the form will do the same thing (given you turn off events for the rest of the form)?

Comment: @Enigmativity Because modal dialogues are used to manipulate data entries cleanly and separately since Paris kidnapped Helen of Troy. Furthermore, I doubt it to be very user friendly to display message and question dialogues inside a panel.

Comment: @tar - You're asking to place a model dialog over a panel in the form. I'm suggesting to use a panel and make it model and avoid the dialog and the positioning issue. The usability is identical.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, but you got confused or we are talking across purposes. I asked how to position a form centered above another form (the panels do not really matter - I've mentioned them only to explain that there are subforms through panels used). This new form should neither replace the calling form nor should it have the same size as it. In fact, the dialogue form can be much larger or smaller than the form which opens it.

Comment: @tar - Fair enough. You're right. I didn't understand what you were after. Indeed we were ***at cross purposes***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by try & error.

When creating a ModalForm you need to set the `Owner` of the created ModalForm to the `TopLevelControl` of the calling form:

```
FormModal formModal = new FormModal() { Owner = this.TopLevelControl as Form };
```

This also works when creating another ModalForm from an existing ModalForm (then the existing ModalForm itself is the `TopLevelControl`).

Thereby, you ensure that the `Owner` of the created ModalForm always has the **correct screen location** by which you can set the centered position of the ModalForm within its `FormLoad()` method programmatically:

```
int centerX   = (this.Owner != null) ? this.Owner.Location.X + (this.Owner.Width  / 2) : screen.WorkingArea.Width  / 2;
int centerY   = (this.Owner != null) ? this.Owner.Location.Y + (this.Owner.Height / 2) : screen.WorkingArea.Height / 2;
int locationX = (centerX - (this.Width  / 2) > 0) ? centerX - (this.Width  / 2) : 0;
int locationY = (centerY - (this.Height / 2) > 0) ? centerY - (this.Height / 2) : 0;

if (locationX > screen.WorkingArea.Width)  { locationX = screen.WorkingArea.Width  - this.Width;  }
if (locationY > screen.WorkingArea.Height) { locationY = screen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height; }

this.Location      = new Point(locationX, locationY);
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

This ensures that the ModalForm is either opened centered above the calling form without the use of `Parent` and `CenterParent` -or- (if no `Owner` has been set) centered on the screen without the use of `CenterScreen`.

It is also ensured that the ModalForm will always be opened within the boundaries of the actual screen.

Answer (score -1):

I have something that could help you:

```
private Form Activeform = null;

private void OpenChildForm(Form childForm)
{
    if (Activeform != null)
    {
        Activeform.Close();
    }

    Activeform = childForm;
    childForm.Visible = false;
    childForm.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(32, 30, 45);
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel1.Controls.Add(childForm);
    panel1.Tag = childForm;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
}
```

This way you have the method reusable.
Example of what you would call it

```
OpenChildForm(new Form1());
```

Comment: You misunderstood the problem as your code is for handling forms within a panel  control and not about centering modal dialogue forms.